# Loading a spark DF from S3, multiple files. Which of these approaches is best?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-athena

I have a s3 bucket with partitioned data underlying Athena.  Using Athena I see there are 104 billion rows in my table. This about 2 years of data. 
Let's call it `big_table`.

Partitioning is by day, by hour so 07-12-2018-00,01,02 ... 24 for each day.  Athena field is `partition_datetime`.

In my use case I need the data from 1 month only, which is about 400 million rows.

So the question has arisen - load directly from:
1. files

```py
spark.load(['s3://my_bucket/my_schema/my_table_directory/07-01-2018-00/file.snappy.parquet',\
         's3://my_bucket/my_schema/my_table_directory/07-01-2018-01/file.snappy.parquet' ],\
         .
         .
         .
         's3://my_bucket/my_schema/my_table_directory/07-31-2018-23/file.snappy.parquet'])
```

or 2. via pyspark using SQL

```py
df = spark.read.parquet('s3://my_bucket/my_schema/my_table_directory')
df = df.registerTempTable('tmp')
df = spark.sql("select * from my_schema.my_table_directory where partition_datetime >= '07-01-2018-00' and partition_datetime < '08-01-2018-00'")
```

I think #1 is more efficient because we are only bringing in the data for the period in question.

2 seems inefficient to me because the entire 104 billion rows (or more accurately partition_datetime fields) have to be traversed to satisfy the SELECT.  I'm counseled that this really isn't an issue because of lazy execution and there is never a df with all 104 billion rows. I still say at some point each partition must be visited by the SELECT, therefore option 1 is more efficient.

I am interested in other opinions on this.  Please chime in

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying might be true, but it is not efficient as it will never scale. If you want data for three months, you cannot specify 90 lines of code in your load command. It is just not a good idea when it comes to big data. You can always perform operations on a dataset that big by using a spark standalone or a YARN cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You could use wildcards in your path to load only files in a given range.

```
spark.read.parquet('s3://my_bucket/my_schema/my_table_directory/07-{01,02,03}-2018-*/')
```

or

```
spark.read.parquet('s3://my_bucket/my_schema/my_table_directory/07-*-2018-*/')
```

Answer (score -1):

Thom, you are right. #1 is more efficient and the way to do it. However, you can create a collection of list of files to read and then ask spark to read those files only.

This [blog](https://tech.kinja.com/how-not-to-pull-from-s3-using-apache-spark-1704509219) might be helpful for your situation.

Comment: whoever negged my response, can you please illuminate us with your experience which helps the whole community rather than silent negging?

Comment: using wildcard as replied by Manoj is the widely mentioned solution. But the solution I mentioned is applicable when you have too may files that just getting the list of files at the start of your program taking too much time or if you are getting out of memory problem. Few other posts that suggest doing the same thing. Of course it depends what the actual situation OP is facing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662953/spark-error-loading-files-from-s3-wildcard?rq=1 http://garrens.com/blog/2017/11/04/big-data-spark-and-its-small-files-problem/